# Can you check Android Gradle Plugin version for project from command line?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can check the gradle version for a project by navigating to the `android` directory and running `./gradlew --version`. Is there a similar command for checking the version of the `Android Gradle Plugin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following [buildEnvironment command](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#listing_project_dependencies)

```sh
gradle buildEnvironment
```

> Running gradle buildEnvironment visualises the buildscript dependencies of the selected project, similarly to how gradle dependencies visualizes the dependencies of the software being built.

To filter out specific dependency out of all that are printed out in the result you could use grep on linux / macOS

```sh
./gradlew buildEnvironment | grep com.android.tools.build:gradle:
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. What's the difference between `gradle` and `gradlew`? I know that running `gradle buildEnvironment` runs it on the system, whereas `./gradlew buildEnvironment` runs it for the given project, but I don't understand the essential difference between `gradle` and `gradlew`.

Comment: Also, do you know why running `./gradlew buildEnvironment` starts up a Gradle Daemon, where `./gradlew --version` doesn't?

Comment: There is global Gradle installation that is bound to the system as you correctly noted. Only one will be installed and can be used for all the projects on your computer. But then let's say you are maintaining multiple project for your study, job or contributing to open source. And every project requires its own gradle version that in not compatible with others. Like project one requires Gradle v4.8.1 (very old project), then second one relies on version v5.6 and multiple on version raging from v6.2 till v6.8.3.

Comment: Now if you rely only on global installation you would need to change installed version every time you run another project. You could potentially use SDKMAN to manage multiple versions. But this can also be a problem when you will push your code to build servers. They would need to have this specific Gradle version installed globally. You would need to contact system admin to install it. But this all can be managed with Gradle wrapper that is bundled with the project itself. No need of taking care of different Gradle versions. You know exactly which one to use.

Comment: So without the Gradle wrapper, the project will rely on there being a system installation of Gradle, whereas WITH Gradle wrapper, the wrapper will install the corresponding version of Gradle whenever the project is built?

Comment: Exactly Gradle wrapper (gradlew) will check if the Gradle version defined in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties  is installed on your machine. If it's not then it will install it in following user folder ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-x.x-bin. Gradle wrapper doesn't actually execute any commands it just parses parameters and passes it to the actual installed Gradle distribution binary.

Comment: Ok thanks. So two questions left: 1) Do you know any good resources to read about all this stuff so I can become an expert? And 2) Do you know why running `./gradlew buildEnvironment` starts up a Gradle Daemon, where `./gradlew --version` doesn't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231721/discussion-between-renatoivancic-and-gkeenley).